# Is it possible for OS to access the database of any app without permission like Google Pay/ Paytm etc?

Tags: android, operating-system

I was just wondering if someone makes any changes in the OS and access all the secret data from the other apps and send it secretly to some online server. Is is possible?

Thanks,
Rahul Gunkar

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of detailed answer would depend on the specifics of your question, but in general: Yes.

The operating system is what is managing the access to various things, all read and write operations to data on disk, is going through the OS.

So the OS code could hypothetically be doing whatever it wants with the data you read and write.

That being said, in a real world scenario it's unlikely this would be pulled off, without someone noticing.

Comment: But for accessing any DB , credentials are required. So won't these apps have conflicts with their security algorithms etc. if the OS is fetching their DB data?

Comment: Therein lies the “it depends on the details” part of my answer. But again in general, the OS can more or less manipulate anything in memory and on disk. That also means, any credentials you are passing to your database, are readable by the OS as they’re being passed to the database. So now the OS has your credentials :)

Comment: yes, that makes sense..if the DB credentials are manipulated. Is there authority which keeps check of these things? Like there are many inbuilt google apps so does google check these things in the OS it is putting it's apps?